# Error in association Rules

Tags: r, arules

I was trying to use the following code for association rules using "arules" package.

data link (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult)

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
adult<-read.table("adult.data.txt", sep = ",")
colnames(adult)<- c("age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","education-num","marital-status","occupation","relationship","race","sex","capital-gain","capital-loss","hours-per-week","native-country","Probability for the label")
```

Remove

```
adult[["fnlwgt"]] <- NULL
adult[["education-num"]] <- NULL
```

Group

```
adult[["age"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[["age"]], c(15,25,45,65,100)), labels = c("Young", "Middle", "Older", "Senior"))

adult[[ "hours-per-week"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[[ "hours-per-week"]], c(0,25,40,60,168)),labels = c("Part-time", "Full-time", "Over-time", "VeryHigh"))

adult[[ "capital-gain"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[[ "capital-gain"]], c(-Inf,0, median(adult[["capital-gain"]][adult[["capital-gain"]]>0]), Inf)), labels = c("None", "Low", "High"))
adult[[ "capital-loss"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[[ "capital-loss"]], c(-Inf,0, median(adult[["capital-loss"]][adult[["capital-loss"]]>0]), Inf)), labels = c("None", "Low", "High"))

adult2 <- as(adult, "transactions")
rules <- apriori(adult2, parameter = list(supp = .5, conf = .85, target = "rules", minlen=2))
```

Error

```
IS = interestMeasure(rules, method = "cosine", adult2, reuse = FALSE)
```

However, I am getting the following error. I also tried some other "methods" but same error. I would appreciate any type of suggestions.

> Error in .local(x, transactions, ...) : 
>         transactions missing. Please specify the transactions used to mine the itemsets!
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In interestMeasure(rules, method = "cosine", adult2, reuse = FALSE) :
>         interestMeasure: parameter method is now deprecated! Use measure instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the package `arules`, using "measure" instead of "method" as in the following line should work (based on the help page)

```
IS = interestMeasure(rules, measure = "cosine", adult2, reuse = FALSE)
```